# Node.js + sequelize: two foreign keys of the same model

Tags: node.js, model, sequelize.js

i need to add two foreign keys in a model called DataSurvey that are pointing on another model called AppPerson

```
  DataSurvey.associate = function(models) {
DataSurvey.belongsTo(models.AppPerson); // this should have the name idResponsible
DataSurvey.belongsTo(models.AppPerson); // this should have the name idConcerned  };
```

How can i do that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This Works fine

```
    DataSurvey.belongsTo(models.AppPerson, {as: 'Responsible'});
    DataSurvey.belongsTo(models.AppPerson, {as: 'Concerned'});
```